# fadeIn animation for Modal Controller in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I am trying to have `fadeIn` animation for Modal controller in ionic 2, but it still does slide up animation.

I tried using animate.css by assigning "animated fadeIn" cssClass while opening the Modal Controller.

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ViewpicturePage, 
     {showBackdrop:true, enableBackdropDismiss:true, cssClass:"animated fadeIn"});
modal.present();
```

but it still does slide up animation.

Can someone please let me know how I can do `fadeIn` animation for modal controller in ionic 2.

Varun

Comment: I downvote beaucause without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong : http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Hello Mickael, as i said i tried to open modal controller by assigning cssClass of animate.css but still i get slide up animation. I have given an example of how i am opening the modal controller.

Answer (score 0):

You must create two class extending PageTransition and use these in modal options.

Check out a full example in [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-modal-animations-and-custom-animations/76287/4)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will look into this.